Remote Infinispan problem with WildFly 26
I am using Remote Infinispan in my project and my application server is WildFly 26, my ear file deploying on wildFly successfully, but when I want using Remote Cache, exception occurred!!
java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/infinispan/protostream/SerializationContext (Module "deployment.use-develop-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader):
loader constraint violation: loader 'deployment.use-develop-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.ear' @230ca3b0 wants to load interface org.infinispan.protostream.SerializationContext.
A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by 'org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.3.Final' @1c8fa15e.
(org.infinispan.protostream.SerializationContext is in unnamed module of loader 'org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.3.Final' @1c8fa15e, parent loader 'app')
this is my dependencies:
   api  group: 'org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-core', version: "$INFINISPAN_VERSION"
   api  group: 'org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-client-hotrod', version: "$INFINISPAN_VERSION"
   api  group: 'org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-commons', version: "$INFINISPAN_VERSION"

I try to exclude protostream from my dependencies but it did not work, and classNotFound occurred!
